# I don't apply for jobs on an external application site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

When a company doesn't use default the application process of Stack OverFlow Careers; I prefer not to apply for the job at an external source like an HR website. All of those require a new sign up.

Please don't accept external job application links on Careers job postings.

Comment: Noone forces you to use an external link; if you don't want to use those, don't use those. :-)

Comment: And I presume you wanted this to be a feature request for the Careers site?

Comment: How successful do you think Careers 2.0 would get to be, if it didn't allow advertising employers to use their existing recruitment systems? A more reasonable feature request might be, "don't *show me* ads with external application links"; but as it stands, this is a request for Careers 2.0 to fail.

Answer (score 15):

This is the company's choice - Stack Exchange can't (and shouldn't) dictate to a company how to recruit workers.

As you state in the title of the post:

> I don't apply for jobs on an external application site

It is **your preference** not to use external HR sites.

---

To reiterate [aakashm's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213260/i-dont-apply-for-jobs-on-an-external-application-site#comment686681_213260):

Your request would  require companies to "ditch" their current recruitment process and mold themselves around the careers system - I'm not sure how many companies would be keen on this.

A much better approach to your request would be to be able to filter results for *you* according to your preferences - one of them might be to hide companies that want to redirect you to an external site for submitting your application.

Comment: "would require companies to "ditch" their current recruitment process" - or encourage the HR company to use digital means of data sharing with SO instead of making the person fill out an other form in their system.

Comment: @vbence - true.. but until that happens - one would not want to limit the options when looking for employment based on not wanting to sign-up for an external site.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I hate external sites too, looking at you Taleo, but not accepting those clients would leave us at a significant disadvantage.